# How do i find the average mean for specific gender for score?

Tags: r

This is my dataset and I want to find the mean of females in math scores. This was my code:

```
mean(Dataset_A[Dataset_A$gender=="female", "math score"])
```

> Warning in mean.default(Dataset_A[Dataset_A$gender == "female", "math score"]) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> [1] NA

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post pictures of data. Share data in a format that can be copy/pasted into R.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the data is a `tibble`, thus, it wouldn't `drop` the dimensions when we specify the `row/column` index.  We may extract the column "mean score" as a `vector` based on the logical vector and get the `mean`

```
mean(Dataset_A[["mean score"]][Dataset_A$gender=="female"], na.rm = TRUE)
```